# Declaring control as specific type(s)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with multiple control types (TextBox, ComboBox, Button, Check box, Label).

I want to check the value in each TextBox and ComboBox and change the color of the box to red if there is no value.

The problem using "Controls" collection is that some controls do not have a value property i.e. Label.  So I want to write code where there will be no need to define the type of control inside the body of the loop as the type is already specified at the declaration level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the controls and if textbox or combobox and value ="" then change color to red

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim crt As Control
    For Each crt In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(crt) = "TextBox" Or _
           TypeName(crt) = "ComboBox" Then
            If crt.Value = "" Then
                crt.BackColor = vbRed
            Else
                crt.BackColor = vbWhite
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```